# C++ dereferencing an instance

Tags: c++, arrays, dereference, instances

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to dry up my code, for example:

```
void gethit () {
    Gert.hitbox(AA.x, AA.damage);
    Gert.hitbox(AB.x, AB.damage);
    Gert.hitbox(AC.x, AC.damage);
    Gert.hitbox(AD.x, AD.damage);
    Gert.hitbox(Terbil.x, Terbil.damage);
}
```

AA, AB, AC, AD and Terbil are all instances of a class called Entity with variables x and damage.

Every time I want to add a new instance I'll have to come into this function and add it manually. I'm trying to add all of the address of the instances to an array like so:

```
void * p_enemys[10];

p_enemys[0] = &AA;
p_enemys[1] = &AB;
p_enemys[2] = &AC;
p_enemys[3] = &AD;
p_enemys[4] = &Terbil;
```

Just wondering how I could call a function from the instance via the array, I tried to do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++;) {
    Gert.hitbox(p_enemys[i].x, p_enemys[i].damage);
}
```

and g++ compiler spits out: "request for member `damage' in `p_enemys[i]', which is of non-aggregate type `void *'"

I don't really need to use arrays specifically any help is very appreciated.

Changes made, thanks @gldraphael!

```
vector <Entity*> p_Enemys(10);

void gethit () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Entity * ienemy = (Entity*) p_Enemys[i];
        Gert.hitbox((ienemy->x), (ienemy->damage));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `AA`?

Comment: Just realized this was a bit uninformative. AA, AB, AC, AD and Terbil are all instances of a class called Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an a `std::vector` as follows:

```
std::vector <Entity*> p_Enemys(10);
```

The assigning part remains the same:

```
p_enemys[0] = &AA;
p_enemys[1] = &AB;
p_enemys[2] = &AC;
p_enemys[3] = &AD;
p_enemys[4] = &Terbil;
```

You can then loop through the `p_enemys` as follows:

```
for(auto i : p_enemys) {
    Gert.hitbox(i->x, i->damage);
}
```

**So what was it that you missed?**
The array was declared as an array of `void*`
So, in the loop, `p_enemys[i]` returned a `void*`.

Also class/struct members are accessed using a dereferencing operator `->`. You used the membership operator `.` instead.

So this code should have worked instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < p_enemys.size(); i++;) {     // 
    Entity * ienemy = (Entity*) p_enemys[i];    // cast the void* into a Entity*
    Gert.hitbox(ienemy->x, ienemy->damage);
}
```

---

As a general rule, avoid `void*`s whenever possible.

Comment: changed void* p_Enemys[10]; to vector <Entity*> p_Enemys[10]; now it says:

s Quest\Terbil quest basic.cpp|149|error: 'class std::vector<Entity*>' has no member named 'x'|

I'm using your edited version of my for loop.

Comment: @GarrettHale which line are you getting that error for?

Comment: @GarrettHale could you share the `Entity` struct/class's definition?

Comment: Gert.hitbox(((Entity*)p_Enemys->x),((Entity*)p_Enemys->damage));

Comment: Hey @GarrettHale you've placed the bracket in the wrong place. Please check.

Comment: sorry this is the error with brackets, I was just trying everything:
     
s Quest\Terbil quest basic.cpp|149|error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<Entity*>'|

      
it's for the same line

Comment: @GarrettHale I'd highly appreciate if you could post the changes you've made to the code as an update to the question (keeping the current code)

Comment: In this code the `for` loop dereferences null pointers; you need to get the vector size in sync with the code for iterating over it